# How To Change The Color On A Mouse Called HEMZONE USB Wired Optical Gamestart Gaming Mouse On A School Chromebook?

Tags: usb, mouse, chromebook, rgb

If you look up this mouse you can get more information. This mouse is called  HEMZONE the company is GameStart. This mouse lights up and I want to know how to change the color and if it is possible?

Comment: There is an application and a library https://github.com/libratbag/piper it may work with your mouse on a typical linux desktop or laptop, but I doubt it will work on Chrome OS or inside a Crostini container on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually requires a proprietary driver that is usually only designed for Windows or Mac OS X. If you have a PC with those operating systems I suggest you do it there & then maybe the mouse will remember those preferences when you reconnect it back to the Chromebook.

[Amazon page for similar product of another brand](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WEVLGEW) has a [user advising his was HEMZONE](https://www.amazon.com/hz/reviews-render/lighthouse/B00WEVLGEW?filterByKeyword=clicking&pageNumber=1). [Another user said to change colors on mouse you use a combination of buttons](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/TxUJ7XLEF6KK2U/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza): press forward/back button + dpi toggle between auto color change and just red

[This website indicates (under FAQ) that you cannot change the color of this particular mouse](http://gamestart.sg/shop/pc/pc-hardware/mice/hemzone-gamestart-mouse/). This is echoed by some amazon users as well.